# My OnClickListener is not firing

Tags: android, button, onclick

Can someone please help me?

I have been searching for hours and I cannot find a solution. Why won't my onclicklistener not work? It works for the first time but will not work for the doLogin method. Why?

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        final FileUtils file = new FileUtils();
        final String patientDetails = FileUtils.readFile("/TextFiles/patientDetails.txt");

        if(patientDetails.equalsIgnoreCase("register")){
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        //Toast t = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), patientDetails, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);   
        //t.show();     

        ImageButton submit = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_submit);
        submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {

                String patientId1 = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.patientId1)).getText().toString().trim();
                String patientId2 = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.patientId2)).getText().toString().trim(); 
                String patientPassword1 = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.patientPassword1)).getText().toString().trim();
                String patientPassword2 = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.patientPassword2)).getText().toString().trim(); 

                if((patientId1.equals(patientId2))||(patientPassword1.equals(patientPassword2))){

                    //save to file
                    String result = file.writeFile1(patientId1+","+patientPassword1+",01:02:03:04:05");
                    if(result.equalsIgnoreCase("fail")){
                        Toast t = Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Patient details not saved, please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);   
                        t.show();
                    }else{
                        Toast t = Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Please login to use the application.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);   
                        t.show();
                    }

                    doLogin();
                    //Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Activity2.class);
                    //startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
                }else{

                    Toast t = Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Please reenter your login details.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);   
                    t.show();  
                }
            }

        });
       }else{
        setContentView(R.layout.main2);
       }

    }

    String _patientDetails = "";

    private void doLogin(){

        final FileUtils file = new FileUtils();
        _patientDetails = FileUtils.readFile("/TextFiles/patientDetails.txt");

        if(_patientDetails.equalsIgnoreCase("register")){
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
        }else{
            ImageButton submit2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_submit2);
            Button pid3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.pid3); 
            setContentView(R.layout.main2); 

            Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.pid3);
            btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){           
                @Override           
                public void onClick(View v) { 

                    Toast t = Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Please reenter your login details.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);   
                    t.show();  
                    }          
                }); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if you are referring to "buttonPress" onClickListener, it's because you din't set this to any button. if not, tell us which listener is not working.

Comment: You have to be more specific about *works for the first time but will not work for the doLogin method*. Describe your problem, the flow of actions. What do you expect to happen? It's just hard to guess...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you actually run it through a debugger? I'm pretty sure it runs but you're not seeing a Toast notification because of the context. Try passing in either the Activity or the Application context.

Basically, I'm pretty sure you're not supposed to use getBaseContext(). View has getContext() instead but in this case you can just use the Activity.

Comment: Apologis, i dont think my edit is showing - the first time the user uses the application they see the the registration screen, when they click on the button on the registration screen they are redirected to the login screen. This takes place in doLogin it is here that Btn btn will not work when clicked. I have looked in logcat and there are no errors?

Comment: Just set a couple of breakpoints inside appropriate methods (e.g, the onClick handler) and see if they're triggered.